# mysql: How can I avoid saving the same data twice?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I made a voting system and recorded votes in vote table as a row like this:

```
post_id | user_id | votes | date
```

Then, I add this vote to user-meta table which has a structure like this:

```
user_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

In this table, giving an user_id with the meta_key of "votes", I can save or get  an array of post_ids as meta_value.

The reason I save one vote in two tables is--

### 1. Why use the Vote table?

I need to calculate vote_total and vote_popularity across all posts, this is not easy to do if I save it only as an element of an array in the user's meta table.

### 2. Why use the user meta table?

I need to check if a user already voted for a post or not. The user meta is cached once set. So, I only need to do a check of in_array($post_id, $my_voted_posts). If without the user-meta table, for each post the user visit, I will have to check the vote table.

### Is there a better way?

Although my voting system works fine. But somehow I feel this is not efficient way of doing this. I would like to consult you professionals, to learn how I can improve it for better performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, I think checking the vote table is fine if you have an efficient index. You can use [composite indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to index `post_id` and `user_id`, which will make a query like `select * from votes where post_id = X and vote_id = Y` fairly performant.

There will come a point where you will need to denormalize your data for speed, but I don't think it should be in the same layer as your normalized data. Perhaps you can use redis / memcache for the user metadata?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I am not doing things wrong way. yes, So, I'm not going to worry about this.